# C# and chilkat http with memory mangement

Tags: c#, memory-management, chilkat

I am trying to create a account creator of my own website and using chilkat.

the code just get stuck at a particular place every time and then nothing happens, even break does not responds. have a look on the image
[image]

And i have no idea how to fix it as

```
do
{
    resp = http.PostUrlEncoded(domain, req);
} while (resp == null || resp.BodyStr == "");
```

it works perfectly but after some time it gets stuck.

2nd question, this app eats up a lot of memory as it works, i mean when i start it, it runs at 20mb but as it start execution it goes upto 200+ mb. I have made sure that no memory is wasted by extra NEW keywords, but still memory is a very big issue